# Apache 2.4 https Reverse Proxy not working

Tags: apache, ssl, https, xampp, reverse-proxy

Trying to reverse proxy with https only. All though the ssl & https works with the chosen domain, it is directing to the apache root not the desired reverse proxy server.

So far Ive got the server to force https when http is used. I rewrite www to non www. Ive had reverse proxy work fine when its just http but https goes to the "it works" root file with a green lock.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So i solved this issue at the last hour. But where i am confused is i solved this by manipulating the config files and using the defualt text. Not by adding my own virtual hosts and injecting code at the bottom like the old days or blogs would suggest. I added proxy rules into the proxy config file. Added cert paths into the ssl config file and that seemed to take over randomly pasting code into http config as it might be sugested elsewhere on the net.